# THREE.js - position particles evenly on objects faces rather than verticies

Tags: javascript, three.js

Currently I've managed to create a particleCloud with the particles appearing at each vertex of an object I've imported. However I'm trying to get the particles to firstly position on the flat faces of the object rather than the points between them and secondly evenly distribute particles on those faces.

**Basically I'm trying to get my 3d object made out of particles**

This is what I have so far:

```
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
loader.load('./resources/model.json', function (geometry, materials) {

    var material = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials);
    var model = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

    var particleCount = geometry.vertices.length,
        particles = new THREE.Geometry(),
        pMaterial = new THREE.PointCloudMaterial({
            color: 0xFFFFFF,
            size: 1
        });

    for (var p = 0; p < particleCount; p ++) {
        particle = model.geometry.vertices[p];
        particles.vertices.push(particle);
    }
    particleSystem = new THREE.PointCloud(particles, pMaterial);
    particleSystem.position.set(0, -100, 0)
    particleSystem.scale.set(100,100,100)
    scene.add(particleSystem);

});
```

**EDIT - 1**

I've attached an image to try describe what i currently have and what i'm trying to achieve. Its using the front on a cube as an example. My object will have more sides to it.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, could you post a screenshot highlighting the problem? Are you trying to convert your point cloud to a mesh? What faces are you talking about exactly?

Comment: @BrendanAnnable I've attached an image under **EDIT - 1** in the original post to try better explain what im trying to achieve and what i currently have.

Comment: I only show the front face of the cube. This would need to apply to all the faces. and it wont be a cube. 
Hope my photoshop skills suffice

Comment: had the same issue - solved it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36305961/moving-particles-on-face-of-imported-obj-in-threejs?noredirect=1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**EDIT: The previous answer was outdated.**

You can now use `MeshSurfaceSampler` to generate random samples on the surface of a mesh.

The `MeshSurfaceSampler.js` file is located in the `examples/jsm/math` directory.

three.js r.128

Comment: I'm looking for the same thing could you please point to some code example?

Comment: @al404IT You will have to look at the source code in `GeometryUtils.js` and study it.

Comment: It looks like this is no longer included with THREE out of the box. Here's the closest location I could find http://learningthreejs.com/data/THREEx/docs/THREEx.GeometryUtils.html

Comment: @Jacksonkr Updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the position of each particle individually to build up your 3d object out of particles.  Here's an example that makes a cube:

```
var particles = 500000;

var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();

var positions = new Float32Array( particles * 3 );
var colors = new Float32Array( particles * 3 );

var color = new THREE.Color();

var n = 1000, n2 = n / 2; // particles spread in the cube

for ( var i = 0; i < positions.length; i += 3 ) {

    // positions

    var x = Math.random() * n - n2;
    var y = Math.random() * n - n2;
    var z = Math.random() * n - n2;

    positions[ i ]     = x;
    positions[ i + 1 ] = y;
    positions[ i + 2 ] = z;

    // colors

    var vx = ( x / n ) + 0.5;
    var vy = ( y / n ) + 0.5;
    var vz = ( z / n ) + 0.5;

    color.setRGB( vx, vy, vz );

    colors[ i ]     = color.r;
    colors[ i + 1 ] = color.g;
    colors[ i + 2 ] = color.b;

}

geometry.addAttribute( 'position', new THREE.BufferAttribute( positions, 3 ) );
geometry.addAttribute( 'color', new THREE.BufferAttribute( colors, 3 ) );

geometry.computeBoundingSphere();

//

var material = new THREE.PointCloudMaterial( { size: 15, vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors } );

particleSystem = new THREE.PointCloud( geometry, material );
scene.add( particleSystem );
```

source: [this threejs example](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_buffergeometry_particles)

Comment: i think he asks to fill faces, and since he talks about an object he imports it may be harder than the algorithm for cube's faces... :/