# How fill a sphere with random particles in three.js

Tags: three.js

I read the excelent question about random populate the *surface* of a sphere with *particles*: [How to make a sphere made out of random particles in three.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31511801/how-to-make-a-sphere-made-out-of-random-particles-in-three-js). How can I populate the total volume of an sphere with random generated particles? I try it:

```
var particleCount = 1800,
  particles = new THREE.Geometry(),

  pMaterial = new THREE.PointCloudMaterial({
    color: 0xFFFFFF,
    size: 20,
    map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(
      "images/particle.png"
    ),
    blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending,
    transparent: true
  });

for (var t = 0; t < particleCount; t++) {
  var angle3 = Math.random() * Math.PI * 2;
  var radius3 = Math.random() * 350 + 1;
  var pX1 = Math.cos(angle3) * radius3,
    pY1 = Math.random() * 70 - 35,
    pZ1 = Math.sin(angle3) * radius3,
    skparticle11 = new THREE.Vector3(pX1, pY1, pZ1);
  particles.vertices.push(skparticle11);
}

var particleSystem = new THREE.PointCloud(
  particles,
  pMaterial);

// add it to the scene
scene.add(particleSystem);
```

But I'm only get an disk. How to make an sphere filled with particles?

Comment: Do you need the particles to be uniformly distributed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sampling uniformly distributed random points inside a spherical volume](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5408276/sampling-uniformly-distributed-random-points-inside-a-spherical-volume)

Comment: I'm going to read it now

Comment: I make it, but I get a cube

Comment: @andars, yes it can be uniformly distributed

Comment: There's an approach where you fill a cube with random points and then discard points longer than a certain length, leaving a sphere of uniformly random points.

Answer (score 5):

one angle is not enough, that is why you get a disk

create a random normal vector

```
var randomDirection = new THREE.Vector3(Math.random()-0.5,Math.random()-0.5,Math.random()-0.5).normalize();
```

create random distance as you did before

```
var radius3 = Math.random() * 350 + 1;
```

a random point in a sphere around origin will be

```
var randomParticle = randomDirection.multiplyScalar(radius3);
```

for a better distribution use some better generator than Math.random