# moving particles on face of imported *.obj in threejs

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I'm uploading via dat.gui a 3D *.obj (e.g. a cube) with 8 vertices and 6 faces (vertex indices). Although I can successfully move my points to the vertices, I cannot evenly distribute them on the faces of the model.

This is my process so far:

**(1) LOAD OBJECT FILE**

The example *.obj is quite simple:

```
v 5.526871 -3.827843 1.523720
v 5.526871 -1.827843 1.523720
v 5.526871 -3.827843 -0.476280
v 5.526871 -1.827843 -0.476280
v 7.526871 -3.827843 1.523720
v 7.526871 -1.827843 1.523720
v 7.526871 -3.827843 -0.476280
v 7.526871 -1.827843 -0.476280
s off
f 2 4 3 1
f 4 8 7 3
f 8 6 5 7
f 6 2 1 5
f 1 3 7 5
f 6 8 4 2
```

**(2) TRIM ITS VERTICES & FACES**

I'm using RegEx patterns to trim the vertices and faces and then push them to my geometry.

```
var faces_pattern1 = /f( +[\d]+)( [\d]+)( [\d]+)( [\d]+)?/g; // f vertex vertex vertex ...
if ( (result = faces_pattern1.exec(line) ) !== null ) {
   faces_pattern1.exec(line); 
   if ( result[ 4 ] === undefined ) {
        faces1.push( [
            parseInt( result[ 1 ] ) - 1,
            parseInt( result[ 2 ] ) - 1,
            parseInt( result[ 3 ] ) - 1
        ] );
    } else {
        faces1.push( [
            parseInt( result[ 1 ] ) - 1,
            parseInt( result[ 2 ] ) - 1,
            parseInt( result[ 3 ] ) - 1,
            parseInt( result[ 4 ] ) - 1
         ] );
    }
}
// push faces to geometry
for (var i = 0; i < faces1.length; i++) {
    this.renderer.geometry.faces.push( new THREE.Face3( faces1[i][0], faces1[i][1], faces1[i][2], faces1[i][3] ) );
}
```

**(3) MOVE PARTICLES ON VERTICES**

I have a number of particles, which i position to the vertices. This works fine.

```
var lg = allParticle.length;
for( var i = 0; i < lg; i++ ){
    var p = allParticle[i];
    p.diffX = ( vertices[h][0] * scale - p.x );
    p.diffY = ( -vertices[h][1] * scale - p.y );
    p.diffZ = ( -vertices[h][2] * scale - p.z );
    h += 1;
    if( h > nbVertices - 1 ) h = 0;
}
```

**(4) DISTRIBUTE PARTICLES ON FACES**

I now have a toggle, where i want to evenly spread the same particles on the faces of the cube. I try to do this using GeometryUtils.randomPointsInGeometry

```
var randomPointPositions = THREE.GeometryUtils.randomPointsInGeometry( this.renderer.geometry, lg  );
this.renderer.geometry.computeBoundingBox();
for( var i = 0; i < randomPointPositions.length; i++ ){

  var p = allParticle[i];
  p.diffX = randomPointPositions[i].x * scale ;
  p.diffY = randomPointPositions[i].y * scale;
  p.diffZ = randomPointPositions[i].z * scale ;
}
```

This distributes the points only on the x axis and not evenly on the area of the face. Any clues?

--
These are the faces (THREE.Face3) I'm getting:

```
{a: 1, b: 3, c: 2, normal: T…E.Vector3, vertexNormals: Array[0]…}
{a: 3, b: 7, c: 6, normal: T…E.Vector3, vertexNormals: Array[0]…}
{a: 7, b: 5, c: 4, normal: T…E.Vector3, vertexNormals: Array[0]…}
{a: 5, b: 1, c: 0, normal: T…E.Vector3, vertexNormals: Array[0]…}
{a: 0, b: 2, c: 6, normal: T…E.Vector3, vertexNormals: Array[0]…}
{a: 5, b: 7, c: 3, normal: T…E.Vector3, vertexNormals: Array[0]…}
```

Their calculated _area is always zero.

Similar question:
[THREE.js - position particles evenly on objects faces rather than verticies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31289577/three-js-position-particles-evenly-on-objects-faces-rather-than-verticies)

Comment: I remember three.js has an .obj parser so you shouldn't need to duplicate the work. once you load the mesh, you can choose not to render it, but can still access vertices/faces/compute normals/etc.

Comment: thanks! I'm in fact loading the object without rendering it and just read its vertices/faces values. This works great; I'm stuck in the fourth step though.

Comment: I tried also the OBJLoader Method. The mesh loads properly, then I do:         object.traverse( function ( child ) {
 if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {
  var randomPointPositions = THREE.GeometryUtils.randomPointsInBufferGeometry( child, 5000 );
}      but get "Cannot read property 'position' of undefined" at GeometryUtils.js:190 (vertices = geometry.attributes.position.array)

Comment: strike that previous comments -- silly typo » should be child.geometry

Answer (score 3):

ok - it took me a while, but I solved it.

I tried the OBJLoader Method as suggested by G.Profenza.

Basically load the object, get its mesh, use the GeometryUtils.randomPointsinBufferGeometry and then move the particles to the vector3 you get:

```
OBJLoader: function() {
        var manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
        manager.onProgress = function ( item, loaded, total ) {
            console.log( item, loaded, total );
        };

        var onProgress = function ( xhr ) {
            if ( xhr.lengthComputable ) {
                var percentComplete = xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100;
                console.log( Math.round(percentComplete, 2) + '% downloaded' );
            }
        };

        var onError = function ( xhr ) {
            console.log ("ERROR", xhr);
        };

        var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader( manager );
        var allParticle = this.scene.getParticles();
        var lg = allParticle.length;
        var scale = this.renderer.scale;    
        loader.load( '/data/cube_02.obj', function ( object ) {
            object.traverse( function ( child ) {
            if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {
                console.log (" === CHILD === ");
                console.log (child.geometry);
                var randomPointPositions = THREE.GeometryUtils.randomPointsInBufferGeometry( child.geometry, lg  );


                console.log (randomPointPositions[0].x, randomPointPositions[0].y, randomPointPositions[0].z );


                for( var i = 0; i < randomPointPositions.length; i++ ){

                   var p = allParticle[i];
                   p.diffX = randomPointPositions[i].x * scale -p.x ;
                   p.diffY = randomPointPositions[i].y * scale -p.y;
                   p.diffZ = randomPointPositions[i].z * scale -p.z;
                }

            }

        } );


        //object.position.y = - 95;
        //this.renderer.sceneGL.add(object);

        }, onProgress, onError );



    }
```